# Unity - Fading mesh particles

Tags: unity, shaders, particles

Is there any ways to fade mesh particles like color over lifetime method with addictive shader. I have little to no understandings of shader coding, and fade rendering issue kicks in even with vertex color shader. Any idea guys?

Comment: It seems this question has answer :  [A](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/134660/unity-doesnt-change-particle-color-when-render-is-set-to-mesh-probably-a-bug) , [B](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/154231/how-can-i-make-a-shader-that-will-make-a-cube-or-any-object-invisible/154236#154236)

Answer (score 1):

In a very general way of an answer, fading particles is done by reducing the colour or, more commonly, the alpha value (opacity) of the particle, as a function of time. The colour values of a particle are usually (R,G,B,A).

We can say that at the beginning of a particles lifetime, it's opacity should be 1.0, and when it's lifetime reaches zero, it's opacity should also be zero.

So let's say that the particles lifetime is 5 seconds, and that an average update is 16 milliseconds, or 0.016 seconds.

From this, we know that the rate of change in opacity will be -0.2 opacity per second (-1.0/5.0).

Now that we know how fast to reduce the particles opacity per second, we can interpolate per update:

```
Op + dOp * dT = Op'
```

first step follows:

```
1.0 + (-0.2 * 0.016) = Op'

= 1.0 + (-0.032) = 0.9968
```

If the particle effect is continuous, then when lifetime reaches 0, you can reset it's position to the emitter and set it's opacity back to 1.0.

Alternatively:

```
Op = current lifetime/max lifetime
```

This is simpler percentage based computation of opacity.

How you actually update the current values is more implementation specific, so I suggest you do some reading into Unity shader coding, to get comfortable with the basics, then experiment with the above information.