# Why is my color on my obj not showing in Unity!

Tags: unity, obj

I've been trying to import my full-color obj files to unity for a while now, but I can't get them to be in color. All of the colors show up in Meshlab, but not in Unity. All of the youtube videos I have watched have said that I need some sort of texture file but my obj doesn't have one. It is just the obj and it somehow has color in Meshlab. Is there some sort of setting I need to change in Unity? If I need a texture file for it to work, is there a way I can extract the texture file(s) from the obj?

Comment: It sounds like you're using a material/shader that does not use vertex colours. The default material in Unity doesn't read that data channel. [Have you tried using a material with vertex colour support](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/a/134682/39518)?

Comment: I am new to unity, so I don't know much about textures. I don't know what vertex color support is, so I don't know if it applies to what I'm doing. I forgot to mention that I'm trying to import 3d scans which when I download it, I only get an obj.

Comment: That's why I'm linking you to a shader you can use directly.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the link. It did not work with .obj. But after I open the obj in MeshLab, exported as .dae and imported to Unity, it worked!

Comment: Remember to mark this answer as Accepted if it worked for you, by clicking the checkmark icon to the left of the answer.